# PYTHON: write list contents to new file + jump line

Tags: python, string, list

Hello so I have a list L and want to write it's contents to a new file, and jump a line after each item. This is my code:
(suppose L exists)

```
file = open(filename, "w+")
for i in range(len(L)):
    file.write(L[i] \n)
file.close()
```

the problem is that I can't to \n because it says unexpected character after line continuation character... what should I do please

edit: I FOUND IT ALONE !! you need to do 
file.write(L[i] + "\n")

Comment: tss, you need to use "" to quite what you want to write into your file, e.g. via file.write("%s\n" % L[i])

Comment: i prefer my own solution because i got it myself

Comment: @whohasfriends you should add the solution as an Answer to this question and select it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.write(L[i] \n)
```

is not working because you need to don't concat `L[i]` and `\n`. Apart from (which only work if L[i] contains an object of type string,

```
file = open(filename, "w+")
for i in range(len(L)):
    file.write(L[i])
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

you can use

```
file = open(filename, "w+")
for i in range(len(L)):
    file.write("%s\n" % L[i])
file.close()
```

. By the way, it is preferable to use the `with` keyword

```
with open(filename, "w+") as file:
    for i in range(len(L)):
        file.write("%s\n" % L[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you answered your own question, but here you can use `with open as file` and `writelines`; just add a `'\n'` to L this will add a newline without disturbing L inplace. This is way more  readable  and will be much more efficient!

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as file:
    file.writelines(L + '\n')
```